Covering a $4\times 4\times 4$ cube with $2\times 2\times 1$ squares
Covering a $4\times 4\times 4$ cube with $2\times 2\times 1$ squares.
I am trying to solve the above problem, hoping it has a connection to the problem of finding the number of perfect matchings in the square, which is solved by Kasteleyn's formula.
I tried programming the $4\times 4\times 4$ cube using dynamic programming but I guess the code wasn't efficient enough because it didn't finish after several hours.
I have a guess that the number might be $61731 = 3^2 \cdot 19^2$ and I'd like to check that to see if I'm in the right track.

You never stated a problem, but it seems from context you want to count the number of ways to cover a 4x4x4 cube with 2x2x1 tiles.

I don't see an obvious way to approach this. Is it feasible to share your code?

Squares would just be 2 x 2, not 2 x 2 x 1 (that would be a rectangular prism).

The following SAS code finds in a few seconds that there are $44913$ tilings.
proc optmodel;
   set CELLS = 1..4 cross 1..4 cross 1..4;
   num numBoxes init 0;
   set BOXES = 1..numBoxes;
   set <num,num,num> CELLS_b {BOXES};
   for {<di,dj,dk> in {<1,2,2>,<2,1,2>,<2,2,1>}} do;
      for {<i,j,k> in CELLS: <i+di-1,j+dj-1,k+dk-1> in CELLS} do;
         numBoxes = numBoxes + 1;
         CELLS_b[numBoxes] = i..i+di-1 cross j..j+dj-1 cross k..k+dk-1;
      end;
   end;

   var IsBox {BOXES} binary;
   con Partition {<i,j,k> in CELLS}:
      sum {b in BOXES: <i,j,k> in CELLS_b[b]} IsBox[b] = 1;

   solve with clp / findallsolns;
quit;


I get the same result with my own software.
